# Failed to resolve: support-compat unable to identify the error repository

Tags: android

I am getting an error failed to resolve: support-compat in Android Studio while trying to build. I could not identify which repository is having the error. please see my app grundle. How to check which repository is failed or anything I need to add in project grundle. please suggest me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.beingdev.magicprint"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "5c3d7b9b-1874-463f-8081-1c3439ccb3ea",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.5@aar'

    //database operation lib
    implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    //google play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'

    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'

    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'

    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"

    implementation 'com.webianks.library:easy-feedback:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.geniusforapp.fancydialog:FancyDialog:0.1.4'

    implementation('com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:1.0.1@aar')

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'



    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.yesidlazaro:GmailBackground:1.2.0'

    //Field and method binding for Android views which uses annotation processing
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1',{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'

    //Libraries I've included
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'

    //Stylish edittextbox
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'

    //radiogroup
    implementation 'com.github.Gavras:MultiLineRadioGroup:v1.0.0.6'

    //ticker textview
    implementation 'com.tomer:fadingtextview:2.5'

    // Dexter runtime permissions
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my project grundle as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        mavenCentral()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        //use maven repo
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the same error by change my project level build.gradle file "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'" to "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'".

Answer (score 1):

i think your project gradle need some changes, mentioned below. put google() first.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
    google()    <-------put this first
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    mavenCentral()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()   <-------put this first
    jcenter()

    //use maven repo
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
  }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

Comment: This is not helped.